# R Transpose Nested List to Dataframe by Column?

Tags: r

I am trying to unnest a nested list and I admit to being stumped.

Appended is an example structure... I want to be able to create a dataframe that is transposed from the nested list.

```
A,
-> Coln Name
-> Id Nexted list.... {0 through to N}
B,
-> Coln Name
-> Id Nested List... {0 through to N}
```

...

Intent is to map to a dataframe...
where A, B, C.. become colnames, and the nested lists become the rows under each column...

---

```
A                | B                     | .. n
------------------------------------------
uR96BDuI8YR7gqbc | lTvW5TcIVIVNmE4_LYQ4eA
NA               | 2DT4Lxjyt3F1ZJt8Mt0o4Q
NA               | NA
..               | NA
NA               | NA
```

---

```
  example <- structure(
  list(
    A = structure(
      list(coln = "A", id = "uR96BDuI8YR7gqbc-Ncg9A"), .Names = c("ALPHA",
        "ID")
    ), 
    B = structure(
      list(
        coln = "B",
        id = c("lTvW5TcIVIVNmE4_LYQ4eA", "2DT4Lxjyt3F1ZJt8Mt0o4Q")
      ), .Names = c("BETA", "ID")
    ), 
    C = structure(
      list(cuisine = "C", id = character(0)), .Names = c("CETA",
        "ID")
    ), 
    D = structure(
      list(cuisine = "D",
        id = character(0)), .Names = c("ALPHA", "ID")
    ), 
    E = structure(
      list(cuisine = "E", id = "O1NBNVfXWmk3CvszAhOEoQ"), .Names = c("ALPHA",
        "ID")
    ), 
    F = structure(
      list(cuisine = "F",
        id = character(0)), .Names = c("ALPHA", "ID")
    )
  ), .Names = c(
    "A", "B", "C", "D",
    "E", "F"
  )
)
```

Comment: Maybe you can try `melt(example)` to start. It would be better if you shared exactly what you expect as the output for this sample data.

Comment: So you only care about the "id" values?

Comment: Ananda,

Thanks for the response. Yes, the tricky bit for me is the transposition of the id lists to the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to only be interested in the "ID" values, you can try something like the following:

```
temp <- lapply(example, `[[`, "ID")                        ## Extract just "ID"
data.frame(lapply(temp, `length<-`, max(lengths(temp))))   ## Convert to data.frame
#                        A                      B    C    D                      E    F
# 1 uR96BDuI8YR7gqbc-Ncg9A lTvW5TcIVIVNmE4_LYQ4eA <NA> <NA> O1NBNVfXWmk3CvszAhOEoQ <NA>
# 2                   <NA> 2DT4Lxjyt3F1ZJt8Mt0o4Q <NA> <NA>                   <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: Ananda, you are an absolute star - thank you. I am slapping my forehead as I speak. Thank you!